# How to check UserName taken in parse Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to check if username is already taken in parse or not, but seems don't work with my code, can you please what i'm doing wrong on it

Thanks

```
      func usernameIsTaken(userName: String) -> Bool {

        let userName = userNameTextField.text
        let myUser: PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()!


        //bool to see if username is taken
        var isTaken : Bool = false

        //access PFUsers
        let query = PFUser.query()
        query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: userName!)
        query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]? , error : NSError? ) in
            if error == nil {
                if (objects!.count > 0) {
                    isTaken = true
                    print("username is taken")
                } else {
                    print("Username is available. ")
                }
            } else {
                print("error")
            }
        }
        return isTaken
    }
```

Comment: is there a reason you want to do this and not let parse handle checking for unique username and email when they sign up?  If they try to sign up with a username that is taken it will return an error

Answer (score 0):

For one, you can attempt to sign the user up and Parse will return an error code of 202 if the username has already been taken.

http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseException_ErrorCode.htm

If this isn't your intended use, to query the User table, use PFUser.query to construct a query instead.

Comment: Sorry but in my title I explained well my problem, I wanted to know if my code could be change for something better, because I'm going to look for username if excisting in my classename User if match with another one, if yes don't let the user take it

Comment: well i did offer some suggestions. When querying the user table, use PFUser.query() instead of PFQuery(className:). Also, your code is checking if an email is taken, not a username.

Comment: Please check my code now, with your suggestion but still don't work, what I miss ? @JoshHamet

Comment: are you sure in the database there's a username that matches what you're trying to test against? which print statement is executing

Comment: Yes it exist in my database

Comment: an issue i see is there's a parameter being passed in called username and a username variable that's defined locally so I'm sure it's not querying against the username you think it is.

Comment: userName is my text field equal to " username" in parse, so what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: well you're also passing in a userName string as well for some reason. My advice is to print out the username to make sure its correct to what you think it should be and compare it to what is found in the database because your query from what I see is correct. I'm assuming it's printing "username is available" right now?

Comment: Can you right a normal example to see how you will do it, and apply that to my query, maybe I can correct it like that ! thanks

Comment: okay, may i ask is the reason you're asking for the username is taken is to sign up a user?

Comment: Yes exactly ! to check if exciting or not in my database

Comment: you can just call PFUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock. If the username already exists, the error will not be nil and have a value of 202. Parse takes care of that check for you

Comment: Parse will create a new user if exciting because I force it ?

Comment: take a look at the parse tutorials for signing up a user. It won't sign up a user if their email or username already exists.

Comment: Cannot sign up without a password error ! with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: please look at a tutorial for it. In order to sign up a user, you create a PFUser() and assign the properties such as password,username,email

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object:  [PFObject]?,error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

        }
    })
```

With that being said if your only Interested in the count parse introduced a new method similar to findObjectsInBackground but does exactly what you are looking for, the method is called countObjectsInBackground

You can call this method after you define your query.

like so

```
  query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (count: Int32,error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                //code here
            }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have an error when I do that : (objects: objects[PFObject]  , error : NSError? ) in
                if error == nil {

Comment: i edited the answer with a code sample, but i really don't understand why you are going down that path. Just try to signup the user if the user name exists parse will give you an error

Comment: I want just before going to the next view controller check if they have userName taken before

Comment: try the countsObjectsInBackground as per my edited answer, then if error == nil { performseguewithidentifier("yoursegue", sender : self) }